# nginx: log which requests where done over the same keep-alive connection

Tags: nginx, logging, keep-alive

Is there any way to create a custom log file, that allows to see which requests were handled in the same keep-alive session?

I'd like to create some logs and to estimate how often new sessions are created and what typical live times a keep alive session has in some given scenarios.

If possible I wouldn't like to create debug logs for this but just add one item more per log line for each request.

Comment: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_connection

Comment: @AlexeyTen thanks a lot. This is the answer.
As you sent it as a comment. What do you suggest?

I delete the question?

You post as answer and I accept?

Anything else?

Comment: OK true: might do that next time, but prefer to attribute the points to the one who helped me (except the person doesn't care)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are [`$connection`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html#var_connection) and [`$connection_requests`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html#var_connection_requests) variables that you could use in custom [`log_format`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html#log_format). Just a sample:

```
log_format connections '[$time_local] "$request" $connection $connection_requests';

server {
    access_log /var/log/nginx/connections.log connection;
    ...
}
```